# How to get values grouped by name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, django, django-models

I have a table

```
id name  no
1  alex  12
2  alex  13
3  kale  14
4  kale  15
```

How to get 'no' values grouped by 'name',
should return the following

```
alex - 12,13
kale - 14,15
```

Comment: Your post's tags are confusing, are you wanting a SQL statement or how to do it in Django?

Comment: will every name have exactly two rows ?

Comment: You can write in plain sql or django

Comment: Ashuthosh, no, can be more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid writing SQL, you can do something like this in Django:

```
In [1]: from my_app.models import MyModel

In [2]: result = {}

In [3]: for o in MyModel.objects.only('name', 'no'):
   ...:     result[o.name] = result.get(o.name, []) + [o.no]
   ...:     

In [4]: result
Out[4]: {u'alex': [12, 13], u'kale': [14, 15]}
```

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server:

Use [`STUFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function to achieve that:

```
SELECT distinct Name, No = 
    STUFF((SELECT ' , ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),[no])
           FROM Table1 b 
           WHERE b.Name = a.Name
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Table1 a
GROUP BY Name;
```

Output:

```
| NAME |       NO |
-------------------
| alex |  12 , 13 |
| kale |  14 , 15 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2b27/2)

- [SQLFiddle with more values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c69492/1)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MySQL/MariaDB? If so, you can use the following snippet:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(no SEPARATOR ', ') FROM your_table GROUP BY name;
```

Where the `no` in `GROUP_CONCAT` is the name of the column you want to consolidate.

Comment: OP wants in SQL Server or django.

Comment: I am using django-orm in DJango framework

Comment: Sorry, i've missed the tags!

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a function to return the list, using COALESCE ... something like this:

```
create table x (id int,name varchar(10),no varchar(10))
insert into x (id,name,no) values (1,'alex','12')
insert into x (id,name,no) values (2,'alex','13')
insert into x (id,name,no) values (3,'kale','14')
insert into x (id,name,no) values (4,'kale','15')

create function GetList (@name as varchar(10))
returns varchar(100)
as
begin
  declare @List varchar(100) 
  select @List = COALESCE(@List + ', ', '') + no 
  from x 
  where name = @name
  return @List
end

select distinct name,dbo.GetList(name) from x
```